# Are there a different set of rules for MOBILE css/html

Tags: html, css, background

i cant seem to get a background image to display in css. And
i cant seem to get a div background to display any color either

```
#mlogo {
    background-image: url(/mobileimages/2015LOGOFB.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;


}


#mwrap {
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden
}



#mindex {
    background-color:black;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #a1a1a1;

}
```

i know the browser is at least being linked to some of the css because some of the text im using (mindex) is displaying correctly. these are the divs id like to use.

```
<div id="mwrap">

<div id="mlogo" align="center">

</div>

<div id="mindex" align="center">
<p id="menu1">Photo And Video</p>
</div>

<div id="mindex" align="center">
<p id="menu1">Scores</p>
</div>

<div id="mindex" align="center">
<p id="menu1">Standings</p>
</div>


</div>
```

im creating a separate mobile site for an already standing desktop site.
ive viewed my code up to this point on android (galaxy 4) and iphone 6.
both displays are indentical.

i cant understand why the image wont show as a background of the div and i cant understand why i cant set the background color of the entire site to black. 
the img WILL SHOW if i use `<img src"">` in the html but not if i add it to the css of the div box im using to define different sections of the site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobilesummer.css">
 <title>SSL 2015</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">

</head>
```

and this is my head tag

im lost on this one ... something simple that im making complex??

Comment: Can you add some punctuation to your para "i cant understand..." I can't make sense of it.

Comment: OK  i figured out where the mistake was. i had a curly brace missing from one of my link properties.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the background image because the `div` with `#mlogo` id doesn't have any `height`. Try giving it a height of `400px`

If you want to set the background of entire site as black then use this CSS -

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

**UPDATE :**

This is a [**pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVZYvw?editors=110) I made, I've used a sample image and also applied a red `border`to `#mindex`

Comment: i thought this may be the problem. a google search led me to the "you have no content so you must specify a height" suggestion prior to coming here. this has not worked for me. ive set the height as little as 100px and as much as 1000px. 

the background COLOR has displayed for me now ... thanks for that. 

if you look at my code you'll also see that i set borders for "#mindex".  those borders are also not showing. 

this is what lead me to believe that there are different rules for mobIle maybe??

Comment: i see ... it is in fact working for you. maybe ill have to re do the entire style sheet.... smh

Comment: How is it not working for you? Make a pen or a fiddle

Comment: im thinking it may be something else in the style sheet. considering im using the same one from the desk top site. siiigh....

Comment: Im getting a red exclamation point on code pen. this is after i shortened the CSS for just the things i need for mobile. my code pen looks just like what my mobile site is displaying.

Comment: did you do something else to the code to get your results??. i literally copied and pasted your code to the T and it still didnt work. is that even possible??

Comment: LOL i apologize everyone. i had a curly brace missing in my CSS. but i now i have a new issue lol. the image shows up on desktop but not mobile lol. somebody please help lol

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a height on the divs, so the div isn't wrapped around the content (if that makes sense).

You could also remove position:relative and add float:left; along with width:100%; this will allow the div to expand height wise with the content, that's if you don't need the relative property which it looks like you don't.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i have the height set to 400px as of now and i still havent gotten anything to show. i removed the "relative" postions and added float also. still no change. id also like to note that im clearing my cache in settings on chrome mobile. im not just using the refresh symbol embedded on the UI.

Comment: I just looked at your pen, it all looks fine and working for me. Very strange.